# How can I overwrite vendor/Magento/framework/View/Element/Html/links.php file?

Tags: magento2, header

How can I override following function??

```
protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }

        $html = '';
        if ($this->getLinks()) {
            $html = '<ul' . ($this->hasCssClass() ? ' class="' . $this->escapeHtml(
                $this->getCssClass()
            ) . '"' : '') . '>';
            foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) {
                $html .= $this->renderLink($link);
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use  plugin an

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html">
    <plugin name="some-unique-name-here" type="Your\Class\Name\Here" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

then at afterhtml function

```
<?php 
namespace Your\Class\Name;
class Here 
{
    //'after' is reserved word. 
    //`ToHtml` is the name of the method your want to intercept, capitalized
    //in this case you want to intercept the toHtml method of a certain block
    //the first parameter is always the name of the class you intercept with the reserved word `Inteceptor` at the end. This will give you access at the class instance
    //the second parameter is what the original toHtml method returns. This is the html you want
    public function afterToHtml(
         \NameOfClass\You\Intercept\Here\Interceptor $original,
         $html
    ) {
        //do something with $html
        //make sure you return a value of the same type as the original method
        return $html;

    }
}
```

Comment: Plugins do not work on protected methods.

Answer (score 0):

SO, after long trying to change the html which comes from that toHtml protected method I realize the best way was not to make the interceptor (which i couldn't use because is a protected function). But, to hook on the parent template. To do this I just add a template using a referenceBlock in the default.xml like

```
 <referenceBlock name="top.links" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/my_account.phtml">
```

And then in the template I use the Links block class functions to actually create the html that i really want. This can be off course be implemented in a better way by going through all the links, but for the purpose of explaining, this is ok. Again, this not solve the problem of overwriting the function you want to override, but if you want to have your own html for the links, this is the way to go.

```
<a class="widget-header" href="<?= $block->getChildBlock("my-account-link")->getHref() ?>">
    <div class="icontext">
        <div class="icon-wrap">
            <i class="flip-h fa-lg fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrap">
            <div>
                <?= $block->getChildBlock("my-account-link")->getLabel() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<a class="widget-header" href="<?= $block->getChildBlock("authorization-link-customer")->getHref() ?>">
    <div class="icontext">
        <div class="icon-wrap">
            <i class="flip-h fa-lg fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrap">
            <div>
                <?= $block->getChildBlock("authorization-link-customer")->getLabel() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should use event.xml

```
<event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
<observer name="set_search_product_robots" instance="Your\Module\Observer\setSearchproductrobot" />
```

> *then at after HTML function*

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

     //do something with $html
     //make sure you return a value of the same type as the original method
}
```